# Highcharts, no animation when updating number of series in chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highchart pie chart that will get different number of values to present. My problem is that it doesn't seem to animate when updating the number of series in the chart.

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Segment',
        data: [{
            name: 'Something',
            y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
        }, {
            name: 'Something else',
            y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
        }]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'My pie'
    },

    loading: false
};
```

and when updating:

```
    var newValues = [{
        name: "Status 1",
        y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
    }, {
        name: "Status 2",
        y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
    }, {
        name: "Status 3",
        y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
    }, {
        name: "Status 4",
        y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
    }]

    $scope.chartConfig.series[0].data = newValues;
```

Is it a bug in Highcharts (or by design), or have I missed something?

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kq8L50f8/

Answer (score 0):

You can switch it on/off using animation property available in chart options. It defaults to true.

```
options: {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    animation: false
  }
}
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/kq8L50f8/3/

Comment: animation: false only applies to when updating the chart in general (allthough it still animates when drawing the chart first time). My problem is that the chart doesn't animate when the number of series changes. I want it to animate all the time, even when changing number of series in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with highcharts-ng, which skip redraw animation. So I advice to post your suggestion in their bugtracker.

https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng